# Wrangler Pages file not found when serving a Qwik website

Tags: javascript, html, cloudflare, qwik, wrangler

**Wrangler version**: 8.19.1

**OS**: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

#### Bug

In my Qwik pages project, when running `npm run build && npm run serve`, some files failed to be found:

**Full DevTools console output**

```
127.0.0.1/:1 
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8788/build/q-8b482804.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:1 
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8788/build/q-9f65a413.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:1 
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8788/build/q-e6eff275.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:1 
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8788/build/q-03a2bd7f.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
favicon.ico:1 
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8788/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)
A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
(index):3 TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://127.0.0.1:8788/') with script ('http://127.0.0.1:8788/service-worker.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

**Full terminal output**

```
npm run serve                                                                                                                         [14:02:45]

> serve
> wrangler pages dev ./dist

 'wrangler pages <command>' is a beta command.
Compiling worker to "/tmp/functionsWorker-0.3009066340734492.js"...
Compiled Worker successfully.
▲ [WARNING] Passing --inspect is unnecessary, now you can always connect to devtools.

Starting inspector on 0.0.0.0:9229 failed: address already in use
GET / 200 OK (28.51ms)
GET /build/q-8b482804.css 404 Not Found (99.78ms)
GET /build/q-9f65a413.css 404 Not Found (69.33ms)
GET /build/q-e6eff275.css 404 Not Found (57.81ms)
GET /build/q-03a2bd7f.css 404 Not Found (57.55ms)
GET /service-worker.js 404 Not Found (53.69ms)
GET /favicon.ico 404 Not Found (61.71ms)
```

To try and fix this, I have updated `entry.cloudflare-pages.tsx` to use the new `createQwikCity` instead of the now deprecated `qwikCity` but this hasn't changed anything.

I've tried running `npm run build.server` before the `serve`, but no success either

I've double checked and the files are indeed inside my ./dist folder, they just fail to be found without further explanation.

**FYI** when running `npm run dev` my website works as expected